# Is it necessary to implement multi-threading to my nodeJS API?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express

I am building an expressJS API that will be intended to serve millions of requests simultaneously. However, the tasks are generally not very complex and pretty quick to execute, nothing that is very CPU intensive or blocking.

So my question is : should I still implement multi-threading in my ExpressJS API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not. Javascript already uses `multi-threading` to support is non-blocking IO (event loop). So if you have many small tasks the JS engine should do the work as looking as they aren't blocking.

But if you need to serve many many requests you may need to look into how to scale a NodeJS application.

Usually, you will find that people are using Docker with an orchestration layer to deploy multiple instances of the application behind a load-balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I recommend, to identify the level of [idempotency](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/) an API can maintain. If your APIs are not very CPU intensive but still they are not at all idempotent which means receiving concurrent requests makes your system unstable, then there is no point to implement multi-threading cause it can add up in-stability to system.

Said that, considering concurrent request are handled nicely by the APIs with single main process implementation, adding multi-threading (assuming PM2) will definitely boost your performance.

**Please note**, when we discuss adding multi-threading, It means multiple main/parent threads which are the processes utilising respective multiple-cpu-cores (something that [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) implements) and not multiple child processes.

A nice read to explore more on handling concurrency at db level:
https://blog.nodeswat.com/concurrency-mysql-and-node-js-a-journey-of-discovery-31281e53572e